# Table cells not fitting in row properly

Tags: html, css

Preface: the table layout/old html is due to using this for a email newsletter.

I'm in the process of building a simple navigation with a table. What I'm looking for is a 650px wide table with a header row for a banner, and then six cells equally spaced underneath that for the navigation links. Right now, the second row has one really long cell with the "ABOUT" link, and then the following five cells are way to the right of the table. It only does this when I have an image in the top row.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        #container {
            background-color: #efefef;
            width: 650px;
        }

        #row_nav {
            width: 650px;
        }

        .nav_link {
            width: 108px;
            background-color: #AB2328;
        }


    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <table id = "container" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="#"><img src="banner.jpg"/></a>
            </td>
        </tr>


        <tr id = "row_nav">
            <td class = "nav_link">
                <a href="">ABOUT</a>
            </td>
            <td class = "nav_link">
                <a href="">AGENDA</a>
            </td>
            <td class = "nav_link">
                <a href="">SPEAKERS</a>
            </td>
            <td class = "nav_link">
                <a href="">SPONSORS</a>
            </td>
            <td class = "nav_link">
                <a href="">TRAVEL</a>
            </td>
            <td class = "nav_link">
                <a href="">REGISTER</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use colspan like so:

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="6">
        <a href="#"><img src="banner.jpg"/></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Where 6 is equal to the number of columns in the row under it.

Comment: More specifically to explain what's happening, is the table has 6 table data segments defined, so it's trying to jam the image in the top section into one table data section and thus everything else gets skewed incorrectly.  Using colspan allows it to use up all six table data segments.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the addition. I found an image that explains what's happening visually: http://a-pellegrini.developpez.com/tutoriels/xhtml-css/tableaux/images/colspan.png

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot about colspan.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround would be to define two separate tables, like so:

```
<table id = "header" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#"><img src="banner.jpg"/></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table id = "container" align="center">
<tr id = "row_nav">
        <td class = "nav_link">
            <a href="">ABOUT</a>
        </td>
        <td class = "nav_link">
            <a href="">AGENDA</a>
        </td>
        <td class = "nav_link">
            <a href="">SPEAKERS</a>
        </td>
        <td class = "nav_link">
            <a href="">SPONSORS</a>
        </td>
        <td class = "nav_link">
            <a href="">TRAVEL</a>
        </td>
        <td class = "nav_link">
            <a href="">REGISTER</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

although this may seem like more work, if you decide to add more to the CSS for the table, it won't affect the header table.